# Proving $e^x\leq e^a\frac{b-x}{b-a}+e^b\frac{x-a}{b-a}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove

$$e^x\leq e^a\frac{b-x}{b-a}+e^b\frac{x-a}{b-a}$$

for any $x\in[a,b]$.  Since this looks reminiscent of the mean value theorem or linear approximations I jotted down some equations relating to those, but didn't see any way of making progress with them.  I know that $e^x$ is an increasing function so if I could perhaps show that the value on the right is equal to $e$ to some value and prove that value is greater than $x$, it would be sufficient.  But I'm not seeing any way to make that work either.

The right-hand side is also equal to this line

$$\left(\frac{e^b-e^a}{b-a}\right)x+\frac{e^ab-e^ba}{b-a}$$

But I can't think of how I would prove that two curves don't intersect in a region.

Comment: Geometrically speaking, you are to prove that the secant between any two points always lies above the curve. This is equivalent to proving convexity as shown in the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can consider the function $$g(x) =f(b) - f(x) - \frac{f(b) - (a)} {b-a} (b-x) $$ where $f(x) = e^{x} $. We have to prove that $g(x) \geq 0$ for all $x\in[a, b] $. We have via mean value theorem $$f'(c) =\frac{f(b) - f(a)} {b-a} $$ for some $c\in(a, b) $ and since $f'(c) =f(c) $ we get $$g(x) =f(b) - f(x) - (b-x) f(c)$$ We will show that if $x\in(a, b) $ then $g(x) >0$ and we obviously have $g(a) =g(b) =0$. If $c\leq x<b$ then we can see via mean value theorem that $$g(x) =(b-x) (f'(d)-f(c)) =(b-x) (f(d) - f(c)) $$ for some $d\in(x, b)\subseteq(c, b) $. Clearly $f$ is strictly increasing and we have thus $f(c) <f(d) $ and therefore $g(x) >0$ for all $x\in[c, b) $.

To handle the case when $x\in(a, c] $ just note that $g(x) $ can also be rewritten as $$g(x) =f(a) - f(x) +\frac{f(b) - f(a)} {b-a} (x-a) =f(a) - f(x) +(x-a) f(c)$$ and the proof can be completed as before.

Note that we have used two properties of $f$ here namely $f'(x) =f(x) $ and $f(x) >0$. If one carefully sees the proof one will realize that all we need here is that $f'$ is strictly increasing which can be ascertained if $f''(x) >0$.

Comment: That is both a painful and very impressive proof.  Not sure how you came up with it.

Comment: @Addem: can you point out the painful areas so that I can try to reduce some pain? or perhaps add some more explanation. if you draw a graph the proof will become obvious.

Comment: I mean, I get every step, but how did you know to write $g$ in the way that you did?  And once you had $g$, how did you know that the mean value theorem would take you in a productive direction?  The pain is from the large number of steps that, until you see where it's going, you would never have thought it was a good idea to head in that direction.

Comment: @Addem: OK had you drawn the graph it would have been obvious. Consider  points $A=(a, f(a)), B=(b, f(b)) $ on the graph of $f$. Let the ordinate $x=k$ cut the graph of $f$ in $P$ and line $AB$ in $Q$. Then prove that $g(k) $ is the length of line segment $PQ$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\exp:x\rightarrow e^{x}$ is convex, we have 
\begin{align*}
\exp\left(\dfrac{b-x}{b-a}a+\dfrac{x-a}{b-a}b\right)\leq\dfrac{b-x}{b-a}\exp(a)+\dfrac{x-a}{b-a}\exp(b).
\end{align*}

Comment: We haven't defined or proven convexity in this class so I don't think I can use it.

Comment: The philosophy is, the line segment joining the points $(a,e^{a})$ and $(b,e^{b})$ lies above the curve $e^{x}$.